# Dictionary in Flex/ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dictionary

Is there any way to implement a dictionary with ActionScript in a Flex application.
For example, I want to store something like this.

```
public var orientation:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {a: new Direction('0','0','b','0')},
    {b: new Direction('a','c','0','h')},
    {c: new Direction('0','b','d','e')},
    {d: new Direction('c','0','0','0')},
    {e: new Direction('f','g','0','c')},
    {f: new Direction('0','0','e','0')},
    {g: new Direction('0','0','0','e')},
    {h: new Direction('0','b','0','i')},
    {i: new Direction('l','h','j','m')},
    {j: new Direction('i','k','0','0')},
    {k: new Direction('0','0','0','j')},
    {l: new Direction('0','0','i','0')},
    {m: new Direction('0','i','0','0')}
]);
```

So that instead of

```
orientation.getItemAt(3).north
```

I could go something like

```
orientation.getItemAt('d')north
```

Without getting the following error

```
Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type int.
```

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite a strange structure you are using. Why not directly use a `Dictionary`?

```
var orientation:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
orientation["a"] = new Direction('0','0','b','0');
orientation["b"] = new Direction('a','c','0','h');
// etc.
```

Then you can access the value directly by key - `trace(orientation["a"])`.

If you really have to use the current structure, you could create a custom function to access items the way you want. Something like that should work (untested):

```
function getItemByKey(var array:ArrayCollection, var key:String):* {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var item:* = array[i];
        if (item[key]) return item;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: hmm, haven't worked with as3 recently but didn't you access dictionaries like orientation["a"] instead of orientation.a?

Comment: You don't even need a dictionary here, a simple object would work too if the keys are all strings.

Comment: @kapep, if you need a dictionary, it's better to use the `Dictionary` class as you would get compile time checking and probably some speed optimizations. Potentially, a "simple object" could work for just about any class or purpose, but it's better to use specialized classes.

Comment: @Laurent I would say an `Object` is a specialised class for mapping `Strings` to a value (commonly know as *property*), whereas `Dictionary` is specialised for mapping any other type of object to a value. I'm pretty sure property lookups get more optimized than dictionary lookups.